# What to in VScode do after launch JSON file C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I'm learning a basic to c++ in Vscode but I'm having issues with debugging, I followed everything downloaded MinGW, edit the environment path variable value to C:\MingGW\Bin. I tried but when I try to run it opens a launch.JSON what do I do after that? When I run > start debugging I get two options, I click on C++(GDB/LLDB). It opens a JSON file it reads :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know what do to next please help...

Comment: The json file starts with a comment including a link. The link explains what the json file is for and how to change it for your needs. Basically it describes how to launch your application in order to debug it.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)?

Comment: So how do i run my c++ program?